# How can I port GCC to a new Operating System?

Tags: gcc, operating-system, portability

I want to port Gcc to a new Operating System. Because I want to compile C++ code on the System. But I don't know how to start.
Should I just copy the source code of Gcc to the Operating System's and rebuild the System?
Or modify the GCC's source code and rebuild it. And then move the binary files of GCC to the running System?

If the instruction set is special, then the backend machine files of the compiler need to be modified to match the instructions. But this seems to be targeted at the processor. At the operating system level, do I need to do any adaptive work or something?
Is there any difference between porting to processor porting and porting to operating system?

Comment: What is the new operating system? Possibly there is already a GCC version for it, or maybe a different C++ compiler that you could use.

Comment: "Is there any difference..." basically they are completely different.  If your new operating system is going to run in a CPU architecture that gcc already supports, then the next main question is your ABI and calling conventions.  If you also choose to use an existing ABI, then you may be able to use gcc configured for another OS using that ABI with minimal change.  The real work is going to be porting the *standard library*, but that is not part of gcc itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The architecture of the CPU is known.

However, this operating system currently only supports C code.

What should I do if I want GCC to be able to compile C++code running on this operating system?

Rewrite C++library files related to operating systems? For example, file systems, semaphores, memory allocation, and so on?

Shouldn't it involve the machine language files on the compiler backend?
@NateEldredge

Comment: Thanks for your answer.@Marijn

The new operating system is that An OS with some different part such as file system, semaphores , memory allocation, and so on.